# Twitter API - Tweepy Library - send_direct_message

Tags: python, tweepy

I am new to Tweepy (v3.7.0) and I am trying to send a direct message to some of my followers. However, the `send_direct_message(user_id/screen_name,text)` function does not seem to work. I found a few old threads which mentioned that the old direct message end-point for Twitter had been deprecated which is causing the issue. Any suggestion on how I may be able to send a direct message to my followers with the new end-point? Does the latest version of Tweepy address this issue?

I have tried the following code:

```
api.send_direct_message(follower.screen_name,"Hi @"+follower.screen_name)
```

Retrieving follower list:

```
for follower in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items()):
```

Error message:

```
Error: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change some code of official tweepy api code.

The first change will be of [this](https://github.com/do-n-khanh/tweepy/commit/79772c976c64830149095f087c16c181912466ba#diff-ea5dd38a4efd9ff36c96e04ab0597cfb) commit in `api.py` and the second change will be [this](https://github.com/do-n-khanh/tweepy/commit/c978749edb944394bd412922d0eb30170e0598bf) in `binder.py`

After that, you can can do the following method in your code and use this new  method to send messages.

```
event = {
  "event": {
    "type": "message_create",
    "message_create": {
      "target": {
        "recipient_id": '434259741'
      },
      "message_data": {
        "text": 'This is a new test'
      }
    }
  }
}

api.send_direct_message_new(event)
```

If you want to learn more about this issue [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1081#issuecomment-423486837) is the link where this problem has been discussed.

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm! The following 2 lines of code might help if someone is trying to get the user id of a particular Twitter user. This would be required for the "recipient_id" attribute. Line 1: ```user = api.get_user(screen_name = 'desired_user_name')``` Line 2: ``` "recipient_id": user.id```